# whats the difference in parentheses in IF statements?

Tags: php, javascript

I've noticed in my dealings with PHP & javascript, still learning btw, that the following seems to produce the same results.

```
        if( ( $A==0 ) && ( $B==0 ) ){}

        if( $A==0 && $B==0 ){}
```

What is the proper term for this in programming so I can learn more about it.

Comment: You should also know about the term: [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which is also applicable here (in case you don't know).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parenthesis determine the order in which comparisons are made.  Your example is a pretty simple one that doesn't need parenthesis at all, but look at something like this

```
if ($a == 0 || $b == 0 && $c == 0 || $dd == 0)
```

This is actually equivalent to

```
if ($a == 0 || ($b == 0 && $c == 0) || $dd == 0)
```

because `&&` is evaluated first in PHP as it has a higher precedence than the `||`

IN most cases, when you have complex conditionals, you want to make sure to use parenthesis, if not to get the order of operations right, then at least to make it clear to the code reader what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

The term is called operator precedence.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: This traffic routing "answer" could have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 5):

Due to *[Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)* rules, the two lines are the same.

The `==` takes precedence over the `&&` operator.

Extra (unnecessary) parentheses are sometimes used to make a statement clearer, or sometimes used because the author doesn't know the precedence, or due to *[voodoo programming](http://catb.org/jargon/html/V/voodoo-programming.html)*

Comment: To make your answer better I think a mention of [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) would also help the OP in the future.

Comment: Good call @Adam - but I'll leave it to the link in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Order of operations, as @asawyer said.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

Comment: This traffic routing "answer" could have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 4):

IN your specific example there is no difference, however, there are cases when paranthethis makes a big difference.

Example:

```
if(a == 0 && (b == 0 || c == 0)) {
    // do something
}
```

If you noticed, in this case only 2 out of 3 variables have to be 0 in o

Answer (score 2):

It is called operator precedence

```
if( ( $A==0 ) && ( $B==0 ) ){}

if( $A==0 && $B==0 ){}
```

In your example both lines evaludate the same. Basically things in parenthesis get processed first.This can be noticed better when you have something like:

```
 if( ( $A==0  && $C!= 1) && ( $B==0 || $D >0) ){}
```

In the above example. The conditions **inside** `( $A==0  && $C!= 1)` and `( $B==0 || $D >0)` are first evalulated, and then results are evaluated against the main `&&` sign.

So supposing:

```
( $A==0  && $C!= 1) evaluated to TRUE
```

and

```
( $B==0 || $D >0) evaluated to FALSE
```

The condition

```
if( ( $A==0  && $C!= 1) && ( $B==0 || $D >0) ){}
```

becomes

```
if( ( TRUE) && ( FALSE) ){}
```

which naturally evaluates to FALSE in the end

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is extra parentheses based on the **Order of Operations**.  Parentheses are used to override the usual order.  To take a mathematical example:

```
7 + 2 * 4 + 3
```

Will first have `2 * 4` evaluated to 8, giving:

```
7 + 8 + 3
```

Multiplication has a higher precedence than addition, so it is evaluated first.  You can override that by using parentheses:

```
(7 + 2) * 4 + 3
```

In this case, the first operation to be evauluated is the addition, giving:

```
9 * 4 + 3
```

The same principle is in effect for bit-wise, boolean, and comparison operators in an `if` statement.  Comparison operations have a higher precedence than boolean operators, so if you have, for example:

```
1 == 4 || 7 > 3
```

the comparisons will be evaluated first, giving

```
false || true
```

A lot of programmers are used to programming "safely", by putting parentheses around the comparisons:

```
(1 == 4) || (7 > 3)
```

In a way, this makes the code look a bit cleaner and guarantees that the comparison will be evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

the brackets are used when dealing with multiple `&&` and `||` also known as `and` and `or`. It's a lot like math where if you have the equation 2+4*2=10 this is because you do the multiplication before the addition. where as (2+4)*2=12 because the brackets make you do the addition.

So in a nutshell brackets have the highest precedence in the if operation.

I hope that makes this clearer for you. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the two arguments if you want to check both conditions simulataneously, but by separating them by using two different parentheses sets you are checking each condition for each loop inside the if statement.