# Is there a reason why I can't use True and False conditions on the same page?

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I have three different conditions used to display specific content on the page. However the second condition seems to invalidate the third one. I'm wondering how I can fix this. Whether I put false or true first the third condition seems to be ignored. I have tried many different combinations and it's always the same thing. Whatever condition I put first after `<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) == 'inboxmessages' && $resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE) :?>` the third condition is ignored. I wonder why.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) == 'inboxmessages' && $resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE) :?>
//show main page
<?php elseif($_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm == TRUE) :?>
//show my inbox
<?php elseif($_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm != TRUE) :?>//whatever condition is placed here gets ignored
//show something else
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This might be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993404/whats-the-difference-in-parentheses-in-if-statements  When you have to take a ball of string to make sense of it you know its time for a bit-wise operator.

Comment: `isset($_GET['viewinbox'])` will return true or false, it won't return `'inboxmessages'`

Comment: Also, I'm assuming `$resultm` will always be `true` or `false`, so this `&& $resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE` will always be true and `elseif`s won't be tried.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: It will only always return true or false if `if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) == 'inboxmessages'` it's actually a link.

Comment: As I said `isset($_GET['viewinbox'])` will return true or false, so when you compare it to `'inboxmessages'`, which is truthy, it will always evaluate as true. No matter what `$_GET['viewinbox']` is.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: I'm self-learning Php... so I need to use parenthesis for the order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may regret this, but this seems to be the intent if you are using actual boolean `TRUE` and `FALSE` and `$resultm` will be one of those:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) && $_GET['viewinbox'] == 'inboxmessages') :?>
//show main page
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view'])  && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage' && $resultm === TRUE) :?>
//show my inbox
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view'])  && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage' && $resultm !== TRUE) :?>
//show something else
<?php endif;?>
```

`isset()` returns `true` or `false` so it will never `== 'inboxmessages'`.  Also, the `$resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE` is ambiguous and not needed.

Comment: Very strange how the first time I tried it worked. Today I try the code and it ceased to behave. I'm very confused.

Comment: I had to modify your line `<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) && $_GET['viewinbox'] == 'inboxmessages') :?>` to this `<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) == 'inboxmessages') :?>` and `<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view'])  && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage' && $resultm === TRUE) :?>` to this `<?php elseif($_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage' && $resultm == TRUE) :?>` or else forget it does not work. Also forget about the third line theres no way to get it to work. I have to look for another solution. I'm at lost.

Comment: Probably going to have to force it with Java.

Comment: It works as expected: https://3v4l.org/EGPfH Obviously if both `$_GET` vars are set and `==` to the values then the first one will always execute.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are loosely comparing the result of isset with a string. I guess this is in error.

isset returns a boolean, that is either `true` or `false`.

because you use `==` you are doing a loose comparison ( `===` would be a strict comparison)

when you compare different types of data loosely (i.e. a string and a boolean) php will convert the types - this generally makes life easier, but can lead to confusing scenarios if you do not understand the concept.

In this case php will basically convert your string to a boolean, and for this it will convert to `true` so if your variable isset and therefore isset returns true, what you basically are saying is `if(true==true)`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

You also then check the same variable for both true and false, again loosely - so one of them will always be the case, if you had used `===` then there are lots of scenarios where neither would.

So ignoring the `$resultm` issue what I think you meant was:

```
<?php if($_GET['viewinbox'] == 'inboxmessages' && $resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE) :?>
    //show main page
<?php elseif($_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm != TRUE) :?>
    //show my inbox
<?php elseif($_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm == TRUE) :?>
    //show something else
<?php endif;?>
```

You may have then found that you got errors when you ran this because sometimes you get warnings about `$_GET['viewinbox']` not being set. so what you should do is:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) && $_GET['viewinbox'] == 'inboxmessages' && $resultm == TRUE OR $resultm == FALSE) :?>
    //show main page
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm != TRUE) :?>
    //show my inbox
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm == TRUE) :?>
    //show something else
<?php endif;?>
```

To fix the `$resultm` issue - and I am guessing what you mean here, what you probably want is:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['viewinbox']) && $_GET['viewinbox'] == 'inboxmessages') :?>
    //show main page
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && !$resultm) :?>
    //show my inbox
<?php elseif(isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'inboxmessage'  && $resultm) :?>
    //show something else
<?php endif;?>
```

I have removed the first pointless check of both true and false and simplified the subsequent checks, as you can do a loose comparison to check if something is true just with `if($var)` and to check false `if(!$var)`

Comment: I did wanted to give that to you for answering first but I tried your solutions and it behaves just like my code. I got to give it to AbraCadaver

Comment: It is not about answering first - but the correct/best answer so you should not worry about that. However if the third snippet in my answer did not behave exactly the same as @AbraCadaver then you must have copied something wrongly as they definitely evaluate the same