# Why does this && not trigger as false?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I have this simple if statement but I do not get the results I expect. If all three vars match then I get `not supported` as expected. However I expect that as soon as I change one of the vars to a value that is not in the if statement, e.g. `$Main = "SomethingElse"`, for the if statement to not match and therefor echo `supported`. However, `supported` is only returned if all three vars do not match the if statement.

Why does this happen?

```
$Main = "Main_Other";
$Backup = "Back_None";
$online = "no";

if ($online == "no" && $Main == "Main_Other" && $Backup == "Back_Other" || $Backup == "Back_None") {
  echo "not support";
} else {
  echo "supported";
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: [whats the difference in parentheses in IF statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993404/whats-the-difference-in-parentheses-in-if-statements)

Comment: 1) "&&" has higher precedence than "||", and 2) ANY of your three "&&" statements will [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to "false" the first one that fails.  SUGGESTION: use parentheses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the if statement will always return true if the value of $backup is set to `Back_None`.

Try using below code. Here it will check $backup value first using `||` operator and then it will check the result with `&&` operator

```
$Main = "Main_Other";
$Backup = "Back_None";

$online = "no";

if ($online == "no" && $Main == "Main_Other" && ($Backup == "Back_Other" || $Backup == "Back_None")) {
  echo "not support";
} else {
  echo "supported";
}
```